# Python: Glob.Glob wildcard matching, loop through list for wildcard

Tags: python

I am trying to use the glob.glob wildcard name to pickup files with particular names.

```
listing = ['DBMP','CIFP']

for x in range(len(listing)): 
    print(listing[x]) 
       
pklFilenamesList = glob.glob(os.path.join(input_location, '*{x}_.pkl'))
```

How can I loop through my listing strings and concatenate that with _.pkl files names for my pklFilenamesList variable?

I want to create a list like so :

```
*DBMP_.pkl 
*CIFP_.pkl
```

Update, I am trying to loop through the list like below :

```
pklFilenamesList = glob.glob(os.path.join(input_location, '*{x}_.pkl'))

for filecounter, filename in enumerate(pklFilenamesList):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the list part, you can easily get the result using a list comprehension with f-string.

```
newlist = [f'*{x}_.pkl' for x in listing]

['*DBMP_.pkl', '*CIFP_.pkl']
```

### Update

After getting the `newlist`, you can just loop over it and append the result into a list.

```
pklFilenamesList = []

for i in newlist:
    pklFilenamesList.append(glob.glob(os.path.join(input_location, i )))

for j in pklFilenamesList:
    for filecounter, filename in enumerate(j):
        ...
```

or you can continue with what you need to do without appending it.

Comment: thanks kevin, so would I incoroprate it like so, 
`pklFilenamesList = glob.glob(os.path.join(input_location, newlist ))` ?  Not sure if that makes sense, id need to loop through each in the list right?

Comment: Ihave the exact name, it will be like DATA_DBMP_.pkl, DATA_CIFP_.pkl . But i am trying to read all ths in my `pklFilenamesList` .

Comment: I need to make this line look for wildcards in my other list.`pklFilenamesList = glob.glob(os.path.join(input_location, '*AASU_.pkl'))`

Comment: I have updated it. Is this what you need?